# UIScrollView won't scroll with content view inside

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

having issues with UIScrollView. I have a setup like so:

[image]

[image]

I have a scrollview pinned in the first image, trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints. In the second image I have place a UIView of the same dimensions inside the scroll view (I plan to add content to this). This is pinned to the scroll view and also centred horizontally and vertically. It seems no touches are registered at all when I try to scroll now. I have set a large content size:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        print("The scroll views height is \(scrollView.frame.size.height)")
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: 1000)
        print("The scroll view content height is: \(scrollView.contentSize.height)")
    }
```

I have also enabled user interaction everywhere I can. I am using the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` to check if touches are being registered and they aren't at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try this out, tutorial is in objective c, but the concept is same, 
http://iosfirst.blogspot.com/2016/08/a-tricky-way-to-work-with-scrollview-in.html

Comment: @kex u r problem got solved or not

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,Many facing this problem i hope my solution will provide relief to Devs.

your view Hierarchy should be like this :-

```
View (main view of my UIViewController) – with
-ContainerScrl
--Scroll View (UIScrollView)
---ViewInsideScrl 
----Content1 
----Content2 (etc)
```

**As, the ScrollView only Scroll When its Content Size will be greater then the frame of Scrollview.**

Now Comes the imp. part the constraint Should be like:-

Give constraint to the ContainerScrl and then  Scroll View Should be pinned from all the direction to the  ContainerScrl and ViewInsideScrl should be pinned to Scroll View. Now it will be giving warning like scrollable content size Ambiguity.

Look, if u give constraint like width and height of ViewInsideScrl should be equal to ContainerScrl, all the constraint error msg will be vanished but it will not scroll as frame getting equal to content size,, let suppose u want it to scroll in horizontal dirction then just give equal height constraint to both the view and give proportional constraint to ViewInsideScrl width constraint w.r.t ContainerScrl like 
  ViewInsideScrl = 2* ContainerScrl ;
it will make the content of scroll bigger then the frame.

Lets try this, if problem not get solved we will look further to it.